# Find the ratio $\frac{AF}{FC}$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, median, geometric-transformation

In the figure below, $AD$ is the median on $BC$. The point $E$ divides $A$ and $D$ in the ratio $1:2$. $BE$ produced meets $AC$ at $F$. Find the value of $AF:FC$
[image]

My try: I joined $E,C$.Let area of $\Delta ABC=x$
Then we get $$ar(BED):ar(ABE)=2:1$$
Also
$$ar(ABD)=\frac{x}{2}$$
$\implies$
$$ar(BED)=\frac{2x}{6}$$
$$ar(AEB)=\frac{x}{6}$$
So $$ar(ECD)=\frac{2x}{6}$$
$\implies$
$$ar(AEC)=\frac{x}{6}$$
Any way from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ halves $FC$, then $FG= GC = 2b$ and $DG||BF$ (by Thales theorem).

Then, again by Thales: $AF: FG = AE: ED = 1:2$ so $AF = b$ and thus $AF:FC = 1:4$

[image]

Comment: can i know the software used to insert this figure?

Comment: @Umeshshankar If I am not wrong Aqua uses Geogebra geometry classic

Answer (score 3):

As per [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) applied to $\triangle ADC$ and line $BEF$:

$$\frac{\vec{AE}}{\vec{ED}}\times\frac{\vec{DB}}{\vec{BC}}\times\frac{\vec{CF}}{\vec{FA}}=-1$$

i.e. $$\frac{\vec{AF}}{\vec{FC}}=-\frac{\vec{AE}}{\vec{ED}}\times\frac{\vec{DB}}{\vec{BC}}=-\frac{1}{2}\times\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$$ i.e. $AF:FC=1:4$.

Comment: Thats a good one.

Answer (score 2):

We use mass point geometry. Put masses $1kg, 1kg, 4kg$ at $B,C,A$ respectively. Clearly, $D$ is center of mass of $B$ and $C$ and $E$ is center of mass of $A$ and $D$ and thus, $E$ is center of mass of $(A,B,C)$. Hence, $F$ is center of mass of $A$ and $C\implies AF:FC=\text{mass$(C):$ mass$(A)$}=1:4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{H}_{X,k}$ denote a homothety with center at $X$ and a extension factor $k$.

We have a following fact (**Theorem**):

*If $\mathcal{H}_{M,k_1}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{N,k_2}$ are homotheties then their compostion $\mathcal{H}_{M,k_1}\circ \mathcal{H}_{N,k_2}$ is again some homothety $\mathcal{H}_{S,k}$ with $k=k_1k_2$ (if $k\ne 1$) and it center $S$ lies on a line $MN$.*

Since we have:
\begin{align}\mathcal{H}_{B,{1\over 2}}: &\; C \longmapsto D\\
\mathcal{H}_{E, -{1\over 2}}: & \;D \longmapsto A\\
\end{align}
we see that $F$ is a center of homothety which takes $C$ to $A$ with ratio $-{1\over 4}$, so $AF:FC = 1:4$.

Comment: What is this concept all about, never heard of this?

Comment: Here is one more example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724446/intersecting-triangles-find-the-length-of-a-segment-given-one-side-and-two-rati/3724833#3724833

Comment: Here is one more example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570774/proof-regarding-a-parallelogram-and-a-given-line-segment-parallel-to-its-side/3570806#3570806

Comment: Here is one more example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608959/find-the-ratio-of-segments-using-cevas-theorem/3729364#3729364

Comment: One more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929057/quadrilaterals-and-parallel-lines-an-olympiad-question/2929200#2929200